# Can I reopen Firebase after the Flame plan limits reached

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing

I was wondering when my "download operations" reached the "Flame" plan limitation, can I reopen the Firebase by increasing the limitation of "Flame" plan or upgrading to "Blaze" plan?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade to the Flame/Blaze plan, your Firestore should immediately start working again. But on the fixed-price-with-fixed-quota Flame plan you may of course hit the limit of that plan, which won't be the case on the pay-as-you-go Blaze plan.

If somehow the app doesn't work within minutes after upgrading, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Can I raise the Flame Plan limit.instead of upgrading my plan? For example add 100K "download operation" just for one day to avoid being shut down.

Comment: Yup. Both will remove the current quota. Flame will just put a new (higher) quota in place, while Blaze removes it altogether (since its pay-as-you-go).